# MySQL - How to calculate the product of multiple rows of one column

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have the following table:

```
select * from bestelldetails WHERE `Bestell-Nr` = 10870;
+------------+------------+-------------+--------+--------+
| Bestell-Nr | Artikel-Nr | Einzelpreis | Anzahl | Rabatt |
+------------+------------+-------------+--------+--------+
|      10870 |         35 |          18 |      3 |      0 |
|      10870 |         51 |          53 |      2 |      0 |
+------------+------------+-------------+--------+--------+
```

Now, first I calculated the product of each rows "Einzelpreis (=price per piece)" and "Anzahl (pieces)" like this:

```
select *, Einzelpreis * Anzahl AS Rechnungssumme from bestelldetails WHERE `Bestell-Nr` = 10870;
+------------+------------+-------------+--------+--------+----------------+
| Bestell-Nr | Artikel-Nr | Einzelpreis | Anzahl | Rabatt | Rechnungssumme |
+------------+------------+-------------+--------+--------+----------------+
|      10870 |         35 |          18 |      3 |      0 |             54 |
|      10870 |         51 |          53 |      2 |      0 |            106 |
+------------+------------+-------------+--------+--------+----------------+
```

But now I want the SUM of each set of Data of "Bestell-Nr". I tried like this:

```
select *, Einzelpreis * Anzahl AS Rechnungssumme from bestelldetails WHERE `Bestell-Nr` = 10870 GROUP BY `Bestell-Nr`;
+------------+------------+-------------+--------+--------+----------------+
| Bestell-Nr | Artikel-Nr | Einzelpreis | Anzahl | Rabatt | Rechnungssumme |
+------------+------------+-------------+--------+--------+----------------+
|      10870 |         35 |          18 |      3 |      0 |             54 |
+------------+------------+-------------+--------+--------+----------------+
```

But this obviously doesnt work. Inside "Rechnungssumme", only the product of ONE record is displayed, not the sum of all the values aggregated from each set of data.

In my actual usecase, there will be tens of thousands of different orders, all with their own "Bestell-Nr". For each of these orders, this operation must create aggregated rows where the SUM of the products of each row must be calculated and correctly displayed.

Comment: Step 1. Never use `SELECT *`

Comment: @Strawberry yeah well that was just for testing purposes ^^ My actual usecase also looks a little different since multiple joins are applied there. But this has nothing to do with my problem and thats why I used this simpler example to demonstrate what piece of knowledge Id like to have ^^

Comment: Have you come across aggregate functions?https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: @P.Salmon Well, yeah, Ive tried SUM on my calculated field "Rechnungssumme". But when I do it like this "SUM(Rechnungssumme)" then it tells me that the column is not known. I also found out subqueries might be a solution for this, but if there is some way to do it on ONE query level, Id prefer that.

Comment: I don't think you understood how aggregation works you should dig a bit more but you will probably get some answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you need?:

```
select sum(Anzahl) as Anazahl, sum(`Artikel-Nr`) as `Artikel-Nr`, sum(Einzelpreis) as Einzelpreis, sum(Rabatt) as  Rabatt, sum(Einzelpreis * Anzahl) as Rechnungssumme, `Bestell-Nr` from bestelldetails GROUP BY `Bestell-Nr` HAVING `Bestell-Nr`=10870
```

Comment: The sum(Einzelpreis * Anzahl) as Rechnungssumme  combined with the GROUP BY (without Having) gave me the solution, thanks! :)